# Php - Reducing text length depending on container size

Tags: php, wordpress, post, text, string-length

I have a wordpress based website with plots of movies and stuff, and I'd just like to make excerpts of the plots so that they look like "Word word word word..." with the dots in the end if the plot doesn't fit the container. So I guess there isn't a way in php to know if the text will fit or not in the container, but what can I do to make some kind of excerpt like the one I described? If the only solution is just choosing a number of chars and set that as a limit, how do I find this number? Thanks in advance

Comment: How do I implement the css code with the "..." in the end only when the text doesn't fit?

Comment: check the answer, and also demo link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in css you have a property for `text-overflow: eclipse`

So you can use that for this.

```
<style>
#div1 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#div2 {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
</style>


<p>This div uses "text-overflow:clip":</p>
<div id="div1">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>

<p>This div uses "text-overflow:ellipsis":</p>
<div id="div2">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>
```

you can see the difference between both.
see [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow) here

Comment: Wow man I had thought about CSS and overflow but I didn't know it was so easy. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordwrap function for this which automatically insert new line in string of given lentgh..

http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

```
<?php
$text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");

echo $newtext;
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The quick brown fox<br />
jumped over the lazy<br />
dog.
```

If you want to do it more dynamically that is wrap it depending its container width .. you can do it with **JS**

```
function wordwrap(str, int_width, str_break, cut) {
  var m = ((arguments.length >= 2) ? arguments[1] : 75);
  var b = ((arguments.length >= 3) ? arguments[2] : '\n');
  var c = ((arguments.length >= 4) ? arguments[3] : false);

  var i, j, l, s, r;

  str += '';

  if (m < 1) {
    return str;
  }

  for (i = -1, l = (r = str.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/))
    .length; ++i < l; r[i] += s) {
    for (s = r[i], r[i] = ''; s.length > m; r[i] += s.slice(0, j) + ((s = s.slice(j))
      .length ? b : '')) {
      j = c == 2 || (j = s.slice(0, m + 1)
        .match(/\S*(\s)?$/))[1] ? m : j.input.length - j[0].length || c == 1 && m || j.input.length + (j = s.slice(
          m)
        .match(/^\S*/))[0].length;
    }
  }

  return r.join('\n');
}
```

Now call it as

```
var container_width=20; // your div or container width
wordwrap('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.', container_width, '<br />\n');
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I implement this to have only a fixed number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using CSS, you can wrap the content/description in a `div`, with the following properties:

```css
.desc {
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 109.2px;
  border: 1px red dashed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1em;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: .2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc">Movie description follows here in the box containing a lot of text. This will be clipped. Movie description follows here in the box containing a lot of text. This will be clipped.</div>
<div class="desc">This will fit</div>
```

The magic happens due to the [text-overflow](https://devdocs.io/css/text-overflow).

Comment: Important to note that this only works on single lines.

Comment: @Sebastian That is true. There is a method (<https://css-tricks.com/multi-line-text-overflow-ellipsis/>) to have multi-line clipping, but it uses `-webkit-box`es, `-webkit-line-clamp` etc. I have updated the snippet above with the same though.